# RegEx in FileZilla for Sub Folders

Tags: regex, filezilla

I have a RegEx of `\/lib\/dam\/\d+\/0`

Using FileZilla, I only want to display folders that have paths that end in 0 e.g.

```
/lib/dam/1000/0
/lib/dam/2000/0
/lib/dam/3000/0
...
/lib/dam/200000/0
```

However the RegEx I have doesn't work in FileZilla but does on https://regex101.com. Please advise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set rule

- Filter out items matching none of the following
- Filename is equal to 0
- Filter applies to: Directories

I assume your problem is that the "0" is no longer a part of the path in the respect to the rule. It's a "filename" of the directory.